# Find record ranking based on 2 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ranking

I'm building a basic waiting list functionality for a project of mine.

I've got a model called Subscribers which has 2 columns: "points" and "created_at". Created_at is obviously generated when the record is created and points is an integer that starts from 1.

When users sign up they receive a code they can share on social media.
Every time a  new user signs up through a referral code, the referrer gets 1 point.

I need a function to sort subscribers by points AND time so that, given a specific subscriber, I know how many people he has ahead and behind in the list.

The difficulty is that I'm not just counting the users with more points, but also the users who have signed up AFTER the specific user I'm querying. What I need to avoid is that users with the same points of a specific user, but who have registered much later, end up being ahead.

WaitingList model

```
class WaitingList < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Database Schema
    # t.string   "name"
    # t.string   "uuid"
    # t.integer  "user_id"
    # t.string   "status",           default: "active"

    belongs_to :user
    has_many   :subscribers


    validates :user, :presence => true
    validates_presence_of :uuid, :name

end
```

Subscriber Model

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Database Schema
    # t.string  :email
    # t.string  :name
    # t.integer :waiting_list_id
    # t.string  :code
    # t.boolean :referred, default: false
    # t.integer :referral_id
    # t.integer  "points",              default: 1

    belongs_to  :waiting_list

    validates :waiting_list, :presence => true
    validates_presence_of :email

end
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, one quick question. Which `DB` have you used?

Comment: The database is Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can `order` the `subscribers` by their maximum `points`.

`Subscriber` ordered by their maximum `points` and ascending `created_at`.

```
@subscribers = Subscriber.group('id').order("max(points) desc, created_at")
```

`Subscriber` ordered by their maximum `points` and descending `created_at`.

```
@subscribers = Subscriber.group('id').order("max(points) desc, created_at desc")
```

Comment: Hi Nitin, thanks for this! I wasn't aware of this functionality. However, it's still not clear to me how I'm going to get the position in the ranking of a specific user. Basically to say: There are X people in front of you, there are Y people behind you.

Comment: Hi Manuel, Can you please update your question with models and what are you expecting? As per my understanding, you want to give the ranking to the `users` with their maximum invitations.

Comment: Hi Nitin, I've updated the question, hope now is clearer. To answer your question, what I need is a function that gives me the number of people a subscribers has in front of him and the number of subscribers has behind him. I'm not just counting points, but also when they have signed up so that people that have signed up later will be behind, unless have more points. Is it clear enough?

Comment: Also, I get this error when using your SQL statement: "PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "subscribers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Yes it's clear now. I was assuming you have `User` model having `points` column. That's why you are getting error. Answer updated.

Comment: I'm sorry but even with the updated answer I still get the same error! Also, this is not really answering my question, which is that I need a **number** of people ahead of a specific subscriber in the list.

Comment: I updated the answer but some confusion. We should discuss in the chat.

Comment: Hmm.. I think you are expecting some thing like this. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Suscriber   |   Points   |   Created at   |   People ahead   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Abc            |     5         | 28 Dec 2015 |      3                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Xyz             |     5          | 29 Dec 2015|       5                     |